# How to print a square using HTML (on a printer)?

Tags: html, css, printing

How to print a square *precisely* with 1 by 1 inch?

I mean, `.strong { width: 1in; height: 1in; }` won't work! What really goes wrong? How to calculate this error?

edit: everybody talks about screen pixel and the 1/72 ratio. What happens when it goes to the printer?

Comment: @JackManey you're missing the -> Advanced Options... -> precisely with 1 by 1 inch

Comment: http://www.emdpi.com/cssinch.html

Comment: Can you explain your use-case? Because I can't think of any reason that you'd need, or want, to. Nor does a browser know how large an inch is (though the printer, and the computer itself, might be able to work it out).

Comment: I think even the printer will listen to the user preferences over your CSS in regards to sizing the content.

Comment: All right, seems like I was not very clear. I want a 1x1 square on my printer!

Comment: @HenryMazza: Then this is a question about printers and not programming? In other words, you don't want your users to do it, *you* just need to do it yourself?

Comment: @madmartigan I want to know if is there any ```body{ zoom: XX%}``` that I can put on my print.css so that the output respects what's defined on the css. 1 inch is really 1 inch. What happens it that it is printed around 90% smaller. Even when you export to PDF.

Comment: @HenryMazza: This has more to do with your print settings, but I don't know the answer. Try zooming out a little bit, to `110%` or something. Try searching/asking at [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 6):

Well you can try using the `in` unit in CSS:

```
.square {
    width:1in;
    height:1in;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w5H5d/

### However:

Keep in mind that an inch on screen is [not necessarily](http://www.emdpi.com/screendpi.html#logicalinch) an actual inch. Even when printing, you simply don't have total control over the output, so I would say this is impossible to do accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

HTML Markup:

```
<div id = "square"></div>
```

CSS:

`#square
   {
   height:1in;width:1in;background-color:black;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

What about using css and html mixed.

```
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>


.square {
 border: 1px solid;
 width: 1in;
 height: 1in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're really looking for just a 1" square, using 'only HTML', you're probably going to want to do some inline CSS. Dead simple really.

```
<div style="width: 1in; height: 1in;"/>
```

To add color, simply drop the `background-color` property in:

```
<div style="width: 1in; height: 1in; background-color: blue;"/>
```